# Button visibility in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I started writing a game I thought of yesterday but I'm new to xaml.
I have the following code -

```
<Window x:Class="TapFrenzy.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TapFrenzy"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="486" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="Map">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button0_0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button0_1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button0_2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button0_3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button0_4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"/>

        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button1_0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button1_1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button1_2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button1_3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button1_4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"/>

        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button2_0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button2_1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button2_2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button2_3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button2_4" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4"/>

        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button3_0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button3_1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button3_2" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button3_3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button3_4" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4"/>

        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button4_0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button4_1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button4_2" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button4_3" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" Background="White" x:Name="Button4_4" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4"/>

        <Canvas Margin="91,0,-142,0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="5">
            <Rectangle
                Width="140"
                Height="455"
                Fill="Gray"/>

            <Button Content="New Game" Click="ClickNewGame" x:Name="_NewGame" Height="50" Width="120"  Canvas.Left="410" Canvas.Top="-12" IsDefault="True" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="DejaVu Sans"/>

            <Button Content="Pause Game" Click="ClickPauseGame" x:Name="_PauseGame" Height="50" Width="120"  Canvas.Left="410" Canvas.Top="81" IsDefault="True" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="DejaVu Sans"/>

            <Label Content="Timer" x:Name="Timer" Height="50" Width="120"  Canvas.Left="410" Canvas.Top="262" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="DejaVu Sans"/>

            <Label Content="Score" x:Name="Score" Height="50" Width="120"  Canvas.Left="410" Canvas.Top="175" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="DejaVu Sans"/>

        </Canvas>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

` - however, my New Game and Pause Game buttons along with the 2 labels don't appear. They were there before I started resizing and fitting everything and now they are nowhere to be found. I tried changing their z-index but it did not work.
Any ideas would be highly appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the canvas was not needed in your case.

In any case, I corrected the problems that were:

A. It is impossible (in a simple way) to fill the black square with all the canvas boundaries (the canavas it is not intended for this purpose).

My solution is to put it outside the panel but in the same place

B. The dimensions of the buttons and their edges (Canvas.Left ect) were not within the visible window.

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="5" Fill="Gray" />
<Canvas Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="5">

    <Button Content="New Game" Click="ClickNewGame" x:Name="_NewGame" Height="50" Width="70"  Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" IsDefault="True" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="DejaVu Sans"/>

    <Button Content="Pause Game" Click="ClickPauseGame" x:Name="_PauseGame" Height="50" Width="70"  Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="81" IsDefault="True" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="DejaVu Sans"/>

    <Label Content="Timer" x:Name="Timer" Height="50" Width="70"  Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="262" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="DejaVu Sans"/>

    <Label Content="Score" x:Name="Score" Height="50" Width="70"  Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="175" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="DejaVu Sans"/>

</Canvas>
```

For starters it's excellent, But again, the canava here is not right-way.

I also have comments about the beautiful (but difficult work...) in which you set up the entire grid...

here fast example for some comment:

```
<Grid x:Name="Map">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="486" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <UniformGrid Rows="5" Columns="5">
        <UniformGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="100"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
        </UniformGrid.Resources>

        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button0_0" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button0_1" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button0_2" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button0_3" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button0_4" />

        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button1_0" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button1_1" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button1_2" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button1_3" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button1_4" />

        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button2_0" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button2_1" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button2_2" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button2_3" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button2_4" />

        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button3_0" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button3_1" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button3_2" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button3_3" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button3_4" />

        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button4_0" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button4_1" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button4_2" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button4_3" />
        <Button Click="ButtonClick" x:Name="Button4_4" />

    </UniformGrid>

    <Grid Background="Gray" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="5" TextElement.FontStyle="Italic" TextElement.FontFamily="DejaVu Sans" TextElement.FontSize="14">
        <Button Content="New Game" Click="ClickNewGame" x:Name="_NewGame" Padding="6" Margin="0,20"  IsDefault="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Content="Pause Game" Click="ClickPauseGame" x:Name="_PauseGame"  Padding="6" Margin="0,85" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <Label Content="Timer" x:Name="Timer"  Margin="0,85" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
        <Label Content="Score" x:Name="Score"  Margin="0,20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

I suggest you learn about WPF panels.

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview

All the buttons can be produced more easily (ItemsSource for example), WPF is designed for lazy :)

But on condition that they rub a lot with material and knowledge about it.

Comment: That seems to work. However, would you mind elaborating ? I'd like to know why, not just have the code :) Thanks

Comment: @decataplachat please [Accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sorry! I was out of town. Thanks a bunch man, you really simplified it. I actually googled about the rectangle and it was shown in canvas, so that's why I did it this way. :)